# Seeking hints to simplify complex query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Building a web page to show summary data and a chart. The query to obtain my summary data appears to be overly complex and there must be a simpler way to accomplish. I'm mainly experienced with SQL Server, and under SQL Server, getting row and column level totals is done within the main query. No unions or sub queries required, unless you are doing some more complex things.
However, under Oracle 10g, this appears to be the way to accomplish the same thing.

The resulting data is put into a JSON array and populates a v1.10 DataTable.

The source data has a row containing the date, item and a count of items.
The ending table uses a pivot, becoming 8 columns, 6 for the items, a date and row-level total. I trimmed 2 columns to simplify reduce the clutter in the question. The final row has column-level totals and the final grand total. Any suggestions welcome.

The query is here

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
   SELECT TO_CHAR("DATE", 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "DATE"
         , ITEM_NAME
         , SUM(ITEM_COUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM MY_VIEW
    WHERE 1=1
      AND "DATE" > ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-RR'), -1)
      AND ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04') 
    GROUP BY "DATE", ITEM_NAME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TO_CHAR("DATE", 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "DATE"
         , 'ROW_TOTAL' AS ITEM_NAME
         , SUM(ITEM_COUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM MY_VIEW
    WHERE 1=1
      AND "DATE" > ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-RR'), -1)
      AND ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04') 
    GROUP BY "DATE"
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TOTAL) FOR ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04','ROW_TOTAL')
)    
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 'GRAND TOTAL' AS "DATE"
         , ITEM_NAME
         , SUM(ITEM_COUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM MY_VIEW
    WHERE 1=1
      AND "DATE" > ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-RR'), -1)
      AND ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04') 
    GROUP BY ITEM_NAME
    UNION ALL
       SELECT 'GRAND TOTAL' AS "DATE"
         , 'ROW_TOTAL' AS ITEM_NAME
         , SUM(ITEM_COUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM MY_VIEW
    WHERE 1=1
      AND "DATE" > ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-RR'), -1)
      AND ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04') 
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(TOTAL) FOR ITEM_NAME IN ('ITEM-01','ITEM-02','ITEM-03','ITEM-04', 'ROW_TOTAL')
)    
ORDER BY 1
```

And the end results should look like this:

```
DATE    ITEM-01 ITEM-02 ITEM-03 ITEM-04 ROW_TOTAL
======================================================
4/18/17 1,063,008   460,436 106,715 97,532  1,829,364
4/19/17 1,061,819   479,338 103,946 108,179 1,859,825
4/20/17 1,095,853   536,835 107,437 101,949 1,944,677
4/21/17 1,153,345   642,364 108,940 106,988 2,121,068
4/22/17 1,075,849   633,873 102,459 99,999  2,012,710
4/23/17 913,952     591,783 95,291  100,144 1,794,358
4/24/17 1,036,377   626,043 115,105 98,339  1,977,043
4/25/17 1,079,163   602,237 118,189 100,478 2,001,529
4/26/17 1,110,499   639,640 109,793 103,360 2,069,311
4/27/17 1,119,696   620,081 105,781 108,276 2,061,452
4/28/17 1,125,676   618,763 113,234 96,326  2,057,169
4/29/17 1,026,974   620,059 102,856 96,150  1,940,394
4/30/17 903,913     539,694 83,531  97,073  1,716,114
5/1/17  1,043,598   590,027 100,272 96,519  1,932,843
5/2/17  1,074,912   623,392 101,793 97,724  2,000,981
5/3/17  1,078,865   620,662 101,699 102,900 2,010,014
5/4/17  1,090,501   628,785 110,248 103,593 2,040,658
5/5/17  1,125,984   686,945 128,657 105,356 2,150,037
5/6/17  1,031,267   625,189 117,290 99,358  1,967,819
5/7/17  921,467     551,497 97,482  93,520  1,752,940
5/8/17  1,064,291   624,366 93,463  98,860  1,979,863
5/9/17  1,085,062   661,509 97,791  98,083  2,039,114
5/10/17 1,103,794   634,868 94,364  102,345 2,033,911
5/11/17 1,107,449   617,931 94,420  103,717 2,024,126
5/12/17 1,130,463   647,744 97,616  102,684 2,079,009
5/13/17 1,056,653   621,182 96,743  99,801  1,974,710
5/14/17 970,969     583,865 87,953  97,682  1,831,516
5/15/17 1,075,979   633,102 95,356  101,336 2,003,830
5/16/17 1,094,805   634,421 96,802  99,533  2,026,891
GRAND TOTAL 30,822,183  17,596,631  2,985,226   2,917,804   57,233,276
```

Comment: Ps, if it makes you feel better, that's not so complex a query.. in my last assignment a single report that output the entire state of the business on one sheet of paper had an sql that ran to approx 56 pages of a4 when printed. That was a complex report..

Answer (score 1):

It might go faster if you use 'analytical queries' to perform totalling without needing to run separate grouping queries. An example analytic expression might be:

```
Select
  Sum(item_count) over(partition by date) --btw "date" is a poor name choice for a column
From
  Table
Where
  Item_name in ...
```

Or alternatively, use 'grouping sets', 'cube' or 'rollup'

The difference? Analytics establish grouping characteristics that add an extra column to a report with aggregation of the row. Grouping sets, cubes and roll ups add extra rows to a report with aggregations of a column

Apologies for not giving an example of this; they're quite an extensive topic requiring in depth discussion so it's partly beyond the scope of my answer, and partly that I'm writing this on an iPad with no recent use of them to call on from memory (the topic is that vast) and no way to test or run one, so I'll leave it as a pointer for you to do further background research. Essentially a grouping set is an instruction akin to "here's a single data set, iterate it once and perform these N number of different group by aggregates as you go.." essentially one group would be by date and name (so single lines are output) and the other group by is probably by name (so totals for each name are output)..

then do your pivot. For more info, the 'phrases in quotes' are what you'd look up in the manual/web

All this is a little bit dirty, by the way.. your reporting tool from end should really be building this summary, rather than oracle, though doing grouping (but not pivoting) in the DB helpfully reduces network traffic

Comment: Thank you Caius, I have considered moving away from the legacy table and re-working the processing that builds the initial table into something better suited for the reports. This latest reporting request has highlighted how poorly the current table structure is laid out. Shifting to a cube friendly  table could help. I'll look into my design and how to shift it appropriately.